# Apache Mina Server Restart java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, centos5, apache-mina

I have a rather annoying problem in my server application.

I bind Apache Mina with the following code:

```
acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
```

Where acceptor is an NioSocketAcceptor.
Over a HTTP interface I can shutdown the server so I can restart it.

```
Server.ioAcceptor.unbind(new InetSocketAddress(Server.PORT));
        for(IoSession session: Server.ioAcceptor.getManagedSessions().values()){
            if(session.isConnected() && !session.isClosing()){
                session.close(false);
            }
        }
        Server.ioAcceptor.dispose();

        Main.transport.stop();
        Logger.getRootLogger().warn("System going down. Request from "+context.getRemoteAddress());
        System.exit(10);
```

This is the code I use to stop the Mina server. However if I try to start the server again in the next couple of minutes. (Somewhere between 5 minutes and 15 minutes) I get the following exception on start up:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use

I also tried a simple ioAcceptor.unbind() but there was no difference.
The server runs on Centos 5 with OpenJDK. Apache Mina version is 2.0 RC1.

Thank you in advance for any ideas on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure of the root cause, but I read somewhere a fix for this that seems to work for me:

```
acceptor.setReuseAddress(true);
```

Simply adding that let me shutdown and restart

Answer (score 3):

A couple things I would add:

1. Set your acceptor to reuse the bound address

   ```
   acceptor.setReuseAddress(true)
   ```
2. In your close block, instead of

   ```
   session.close(false)
   ```

   use

   ```
   session.close(true)
   ```

   This will close the session immediately instead of waiting for a flush.

**References:**

Session close -   http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/session/IoSession.html#close(boolean)

ServerSocket reuse address - 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html?is-external=true#setReuseAddress(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm familiar with MINA, but how does

> netstat -apn | grep PORT
>   ps -ef | grep
>   java

look like?

Oh, ok. Did you hit the command with root user privilege?

Comment: They both show nothing. "lsof -i" also shows no connections on that port

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with the close otherwise TCP behaves in this way. See [this](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section4/11.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this now, but I must wait to see the results. Any ideas on how I would go about testing this without putting it on the production server? I normally have around 2000 sockets open, and it is hard to replicate in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
acceptor.setReuseAddress(true)
```

This allows the port be reused.

Answer (score 0):

First check the OS configuration by **"sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout"**,then modify it to 30 seconds;Second **"sysctl -a|grep net.ipv4.tcp_tw"**,modify the value like this 
**net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1**